# Servlet gives a blank page when it should be redirecting

Tags: java, servlets

I'm having a problem in my servlet ("maakservlet"), the maakservlet should redirect automatically to welkom.jsp but instead it just gives me a blank page.

I have tried requestdispatches, response.sendRedirect etc.

Here is my code from the servlet:

```
protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {

    int code = 1;
    String voornaam = request.getParameter("voornaam");
    String achternaam = request.getParameter("achternaam");
    String eerstebezoek = request.getParameter("eerstebezoek");
    String meerderebezoeken = request.getParameter("meerderebezoeken");
    String attractie = request.getParameter("attractie");
    String naamattractie = request.getParameter("naamAttractie");
    String naampretpark = request.getParameter("naampretpark");

    Bezoeker bezoeker = new Bezoeker(voornaam, achternaam);

    if (attractie == "geen") {
        ;
    } else {
        bezoeker.voegToeAanWishlist(attractie);
    }

    if (eerstebezoek == null && meerderebezoeken == null) {
        bezoeker.setPretparkcode(1000);
    } else if (meerderebezoeken != null) {
        bezoeker.setPretparkcode(code);
        code += 1;
    }

    String destination = "welkom.jsp";
    RequestDispatcher requestDispatcher = request.getRequestDispatcher(destination);
}

@Override
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
    processRequest(request, response);

}

@Override
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
    processRequest(request, response);
    String welkom = "welkom.jsp";

    response.sendRedirect("welkom.jsp");

    RequestDispatcher rd = request.getRequestDispatcher("welkom.jsp");
    rd.forward(request, response);
}
```

Comment: What did "not work" when you used `response.sendRedirect()`?

Answer (score 1):

To redirect the request to a completely different page you have to use your `response`:

```
response.sendRedirect(destination);
```

See: https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-5.5-doc/servletapi/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletResponse.html#sendRedirect(java.lang.String)

Comment: Thanks for the comment, where would you put that line? I already have that line in my dopost() section. But I still get stuck at the blank maarkservlet.

Comment: In your `doPost()` method you are using `sendRedirect()` _and_ the `RequestDispatcher`. Both won't work together. You either redirect the user to a completely new page or you forward rendering to another resource (like a JSP, another servlet) etc. So first thing you should do is delete the last two lines of your `doPost()` method.